# Js for loop changing a string - how does it know?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, iteration

This simple function accepts an array with 10 single digits and outputs these digits as a string written in common phone number format. Looping over the array, how does the program "know" it should replace each "x" in format, rather than replacing only the first "x" each time it loops? I know that if it replaced only the first "x", the function would make no sense. But I don't understand how it happens that the program "knows" to replace each "x" while looping over array.

```
function createPhoneNumber(numbersArr){
  var format = "(xxx) xxx-xxxx";
  for(var i = 0; i < numbersArr.length; i++)
  {
    format = format.replace('x', numbersArr[i]);
  }
  return format;
}
```

Comment: On the second loop iteration, the first `x` will already be replaced by the correct value, so it will replace the newly first `x` (which is actually the second `x` in the original string)

Comment: I'd say that is a smart problem solution. This solution didn't occur to me.

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing the first `x` but you also updating the `format` also

```
format = format.replace("x", numbersArr[i]);
```

Let's go step by step

- `i = 0` Before format is `"(xxx) xxx-xxxx"` and after replacing format is `'(1xx) xxx-xxxx'`
- `i = 1` Before format is `"(1xx) xxx-xxxx"` and after replacing format is `'(12x) xxx-xxxx'`
- `i = 2` Before format is `"(12x) xxx-xxxx"` and after replacing format is `'(123) xxx-xxxx'`

**...**

- `i = 8` Before format is `"(123) 456-789x"` and after replacing format is `'(123) 456-7890'`

```js
function createPhoneNumber(numbersArr) {
  var format = "(xxx) xxx-xxxx";
  for (var i = 0; i < numbersArr.length; i++) {
    format = format.replace("x", numbersArr[i]);
    console.log("AFter - " + format);
  }
  return format;
}

createPhoneNumber([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]);
```

Comment: Great thank you, your answer enlightened me. The operation on format string is done inside the loop function, so with each iteration the program "remembers" the updated string and operates on this updated string. In other words, every iteration creates a new format string (temporarily), which gets updated again with subsequent iterations. After the last iteration, the updating process is finished.

Comment: I have one more question. I put the return statement inside the loop, and the process finished after the first looping, why? 

function createPhoneNumber(numbersArr) {
  var format = "(xxx) xxx-xxxx";
  for (var i = 0; i < numbersArr.length; i++) {
    format = format.replace("x", numbersArr[i]);
    console.log("AFter - " + format);
    return format;
  }
}

Comment: As soon as the Js interpreter encounters the `return`  statement then the execution ends and returns the value if you have specified the value to return like `return format` else it will return `undefined`.

Comment: You can read it more from the official [docs from mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return).

Answer (score 0):

It works because the replace method only replaces one 'x' character at a time.

So on each iteration, the first 'x' character found corresponds with the numbers array position.

Comment: Thank you. But I still don't get it. My thinking is: each time the looping over array is done, the program should "jump" to format and start changing it replacing from the beginning (from the first "x"). After each looping, how does it "remember" it has already replaced previous "x"es?

Comment: It "remembers" because you are overwriting the "format" variable inside the loop: format = format.replace('x', numbersArr[i])

Comment: Thank you! I think I get it now. The operation on format string happens all inside the loop, hence it "knows" and "remembers" the updated format string during each iteration.